# Does MSSQL interfere with MySQL on LAMP SERVER?

Tags: server, php, mysql, lamp, mssql

I'm currently working on a project that requires me to connect remotely to a MSSQL database on a different server.

After some research and crawling of this site and google I think one of the problems is that the current LAMP server I am working on using Ubuntu 14.04.2 doesn't have the extensions on PHP needed to connect to MSSQL. I think I know what extensions are needed but I am apprehensive of following through with the installation through fear of losing current MySQL configs and databases.

Is this an irrational fear that I shouldn't worry about (i.e installing what PHP needs to run MSSQL functions doesn't affect MySQL in anyway) or am I right to be apprehensive?

Thanks,

Comment: This question depends on how you code your connections I myself would use a perl or python connector on the server to connect to the remote SQL server and haver perl/python do the queries and formatting of the data do the website can show it. I would never opt for PHP for *anything* :-P

Comment: May I ask why? :)

Comment: The last sentence? https://eev.ee/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/ sums it up nicely

Comment: well that is very interesting actually and it does stir up some questions and routes to explore for my future development however for this project it sadly needs to be php as that is what the client is asking for and my timeframe doesnt allow for me to go and learn new languages sadly. thanks for the good read though!

Comment: Yeah well. I've had the same problem ;-) Sometimes you can not avoid it. But if you own the server (or can get onto it) I'd try to create connectors on the server itself and not use the browser (security wise also better ;-))

Comment: @Rinzwind you are not being helpful, remember people come here to seek help and all you offered was trolling PHP. That's neither helpful nor as funny as you might think.

Comment: @oerdnj you need to lookup the difference between factual and trolling ;-)

Comment: The author of the blog is just a little angry man and it's easy to write about bad stuff in any language with any history, but that's make it what it is, just a random rant about PHP from an angry man. He might be factual, but if you pick just the facts that fit into your wordview, it's call at least biased (if not trolling).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP packages has support for connecting to MSSQL server.  The support is included in php5-sybase package.  In PHP 5.6 you can still use the obsolete MSSQL functions, but I urge you to use pdo_dblib extension (it's compiled with freetds library, but it can be used to connect to MSSQL server) as the old extension has been dropped in PHP 7.

Here's the link to the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php and don't forget to use dblib as your DSN prefix as the extension is compiled with FreeTDS on Ubuntu.

The additional modules won't affect existing modules.  If you install f.e. php5-pgsql it won't affect existing MySQL module, same goes with pdo-dblib.  It will just add more functions.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! however, I had already found information on this kind of stuff and whilst helpful it not not answer my question but in fact the question that it did raise was; if I were to install these packages onto my server (including freetds) will this impact on/affect current MySQL databases and configurations?

Comment: @LewisJWright Ok, edited answer to be more complete related to your question. Perhaps I was too confused by your question because there's no reason for the additional modules to affect the MySQL extension.

Comment: Thank you very much I just wanted to make sure nothing was lost on the MySQL side as the client is still using that and I'm still a bit new to managing servers/installing packages etc.